# Escape TAB in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

I need to pass a tab character into a program from the command-line on Windows.

eg: grep "foo<TAB>bar" filename

However, cmd.exe's auto-completion gets in the way.

On Unix, you can hit Ctrl-V before the TAB to escape the special function of TAB.

In Powershell, `t is the escaped representation of TAB.

Does anyone know a way to do this for Windows' Command Prompt?

Answer (score 4):

If you start `CMD` with `/F:ON` it changes file completion to use `^F` (which includes directories, while `^D` does directories only) and makes `Tab` issue a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off tab completion, or change it to another character:
http://www.gabrielserafini.com/blog/2004/10/26/windows-shell-auto-complete/

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something else. :-)